# How to adjust the speed Animate.css when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I'm using Animate.css on my website but it shows the contents too late.

I wonder how to adjust the speed at which the animation appears when scrolling.

I found some javascript code about the scrolling function.

```
(function($){
$.fn.edsViewportChecker = function(useroptions){

    var options = {
        classToRemove: 'eds-scroll-hidden',
        classToAdd: 'eds-scroll-visible',
        offset: 75,
        callbackFunction: function(elem){}
    };
    $.extend(options, useroptions);

    var $elem = this;            

    this.checkElements = function(){

        var windowHeight = $(window).height(),
        viewportTop = $(document).scrollTop(),
        viewportBottom = (viewportTop + windowHeight);

        $elem.each(function(){
            var $obj = $(this);
            var scroll_offset = $obj.attr('eds_scroll_offset');

            if ($obj.hasClass(options.classToAdd)){
                return;
            }

            var elemTop = '';
            if(scroll_offset != null && scroll_offset != ''){
                elemTop = Math.round( $obj.offset().top ) + Math.round(Number(scroll_offset) * $obj.height() * 0.01),
                    elemBottom = elemTop + ($obj.height());
            }else{
                elemTop = Math.round( $obj.offset().top ) + Math.round(options.offset * $obj.height() * 0.01),
                elemBottom = elemTop + ($obj.height());
            }

            // Add class if in viewport
            if ((elemTop < viewportBottom) && (elemBottom > viewportTop)){
                $obj.addClass(options.classToAdd);
                $obj.removeClass(options.classToRemove);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $obj.css('overflow', 'hidden');
                }, 250);
                options.callbackFunction($obj);
            }
        });
    };

    $( window ).on( "scroll", $.throttle( 250, this.checkElements ) );
    //For applying the onscroll part only after the user scroll atleast ones event after the item is in view port, just comment this out        
    this.checkElements();

}; })(jQuery);
```

Which part do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The `250` in the `setTimeout` function should specify the milliseconds of delay until the `overflow` attribute of the DOM element is set to `hidden` (which I believe triggers the animation).

Additionally, you can change the `offset: 75` to something smaller to start the animation sooner when scrolling.

**EDIT:** It is safer to use Jonathan Tan's answer than to edit the JS file (after looking at the github, I don't even know where you found that). Just remember to change the `-vendor-` in `-vendor-animation-duration: 3s;` for coverage. For example:

```
-webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
-moz-animation-duration: 3s;
-o-animation-duration: 3s;
animation-duration: 3s;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  -vendor-animation-duration: 3s;
```

as seen in the github page https://github.com/daneden/animate.css

change the duration and the longer the duration the slower.

for `-vendor-animation-duration: 3s;`
i mean to change the 3s, if you want it to be slower the set it to be more than 3, in the other hand if you want it to be faster the set it to be less than 3.